# An optimization algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, keras

*Condition 1*: I have 5800 one dimensional signals, where I choose 30 of them and make a picture using those 30 signals that I picked, via a process called *X* (Here, this process doesn't effect the question).

*Condition 2*: I have a model that can evaluate a picture and return a number between 0 and 1, where 1 means the picture is very desired and 0 meaning it is not accurate at all.

*Condition 3*: Now I want to choose 30 signals from those 5800 original signals, in such a way that if I evaluate its corresponding image with the model in *Condition 1* , it is close to 1 as possible.

To be more precise, choosing all of the 30 out of 5800 possibilities is very computational expensive. I'm struggling to come up with an algorithm to kind of replace only some of those 30 signals that I originally -randomly- picked, based on the evaluation of the model in *Condition 1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use genetic algorithms :

- calculate a set of 30 signals that cover all 5800 signals.
- Mix best solutions.